# Missing nuget packages error while using msbuild from command line

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I am working on a silverlight app. We are using nuget packages but we dont check in the packages and the packages should be restored while building. The solution compiles well in visual studio.
I am trying to add a compile task in command line using msbuild

> Exec { C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe $slnFile /p:OutputPath=$outputPath  /p:Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir=$rootDir\Source\ /verbosity:minimal /nologo /m:4  } "Build Failed

Before doing this step, I'm doing a nuget restore explicitly.

> Exec { C:\project\nuget.exe  restore $solutionFile} "restore failed"

This step passes with a message "All packages listed in packages.config" are already installed.

But when the actual build step happens the build fails with the message

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is \Source\.nuget\NuGet.targets.

I am doing a nuget restore explicitly and I have enabled

"Allow nuget to download missing packages" in visual studio and 
 "Enable nuget package restore" in solution level.

My nuget.config has "disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true"

I have seen similar issues in stackoverflow and I have tried all the above solutions that were suggested. I don't have a clue why it fails in spite of all these.

Comment: For S&Gs, copy your nuget.targets file into the root of \Source

Comment: @Will Thanks fr the input. I copied the .nuget folder to the root directory it dint help.

Comment: Can you [edit] and add your full nuget.config file?  Should be comparable to [this](https://gist.github.com/WillSullivan/37025f2af4908a74f267)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do both the **nuget.exe restore** and have MSBuild use NuGet.targets to restore the NuGet packages. You should choose one or the other.

I suspect the problem in your case is that **$rootDir** is not defined and the **SolutionDir** property you are passing to MSBuild is:

**\Source**

In my project file I have:

```
 <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
```

So if **SolutionDir** is **\Source** then the solution will fail to compile with the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

In mine, the csproj file somehow had this:

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
  <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
</PropertyGroup>
<Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
```

Removing it had solved the problem.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, where packages restored through command line nuget command(nuget restore "D:\.." ) not getting referenced when I compile the project from command line using MSbuild. How did it get resolve?